# SSO authentication, response is always NTLM

Tags: java, kerberos, spnego

I'm trying to implement SSO on an intranet application we are developing. I am using [SPNEGO](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) for this. Now I'm having some trouble configuring the SSO and hope someone here is able to help me.

The setup is like this:

1. Linux server with tomcat to serve the intranet application
2. Windows Server 2008 as domain controller (Active Directory)
3. Windows 7 client with IE9 and Firefox

When I open the intranet application I see a GET request going from the client to the tomcat server. The first response of the tomcat server and the SpnegoFilter is a 401 unauthorized which is right, cause the client needs to be authenticated.

```
806 6.117724    192.168.65.50   192.168.65.50   HTTP    284 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate\r\n
```

The response of the client then is a GET request with a flag NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE. Here it breaks. I don't expect a NTLM response, but a kerberos/spnego response. Somehow I just can't figure out how to send the correct response to the tomcat server.

```
808 6.123277    192.168.65.50   192.168.65.50   HTTP    637 GET / HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
```

By default NTLM isn't supported by SPNEGO so I get the following entry in my log:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: NTLM specified. Downgraded to Basic Auth (and/or SSL) but downgrade not supported.

So I'm doing something wrong, but aftert a day fiddling with configurations and policies I just can't figure out what it is.

Hoping for some response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos does not work on IPs, use fully qualified domain names.

Comment: Changed it to FQDN, but still the problem exists. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are your reverse records ok? Did you put the server realm into the trusted zone? Did you analyze the traffic with Wireshark?

Comment: I'm scanning it with Wireshark, but I think I don't have enough knowledge to see directly what the problem is. 

To be sure we have the same understsnding. What do you mean with reverse records?

Comment: I am referring to reverse DNS records. They are absolutely crucial. Yu can send me the pcap file and I will tell you the reason.

Comment: Michael-O. I've got it working now. I did forget to add the new FQDN as a server pincipal. When I did that and configured IE and Chrome correctly it worked like a charm. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The savest way is to the a SPN for the FQDN and the shortname.

Comment: Are you sure Negotiation for IP address is not supported at all. I would expect it to work after `setspn -a HTTP/xx.xx.xx.xx ServiceAccount` on DC. Is it a browser limitation ?

Comment: This is not a browser limitation. Kerberos operates on hostnames only and relies heavily on DNS. No IP addresses (reverse DNS).

Comment: It can work via IP if you register the SPN, but it is a worst practice .

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered the SPN and is the client domain joined?  The WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate will tell the web browser to try kerberos. The browser hands of that request to the OS (SSPI) based on URL in the address bar.  There must be a SPN in AD for the URL.  As others noted above, using an IP in your URL is more complicated, but can be done. If your client is not domain joined, there is extra config work to get it to contact your AD KDC.  Firefox takes extra setup as well.  Solve ths with IE, to eliminate that and them come back to FF when the issue is resolved.